# How to cast object array to generic type array

Tags: c#, generics

I am trying to cast an object array to generic object array in CSharp, keep getting this compiler error. Any ideas?

Thanks

```
 private const int INITIAL_CAPACITY = 20;
    protected int numElements;
    protected E[] elements;

    /*
     * default constructor that creates a new set
     * that is initially empty
     * */
    public ArraySet()
    {
        numElements = 0;
        elements = (E[])(new Object[INITIAL_CAPACITY]);// unchecked
    }
```

thanks guys, Another related question, I want to set a particular element to null. The following code does not work.

elements[numElements - 1] = null:

What is the correct null value we should use in here then. thank

Comment: You should add the whole class and the exact compiler error message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PLB's answer points out why you don't *need* to do that, I'll just chime in on why you *can't* do that.

Let's say you have an object array:

```
var objectArray = new object[] { 3, 5, 3.3, "test" };
```

Now how would you say I convert that to a uniform, generic type? There's no guarantee that all of the instances inside the object array will be of the same type, the array might be heterogenous, so this:

```
public static T[] ConvertTo<T>(object[] arr)
{
    return (T[])arr;
}

var intArray = ConvertTo<int>(objectArray);
```

Can't really work: `Cannot convert type 'object[]' to 'T[]'` in the `ConvertTo` method.

What you *can* do in such situation is test each and every item if it's of appropriate type, especially since LINQ already has fitting method:

```
var intArray = objectArray.OfType<int>().ToArray();
```

Which will give you an array: `[3, 5]`

So a generic version would be: `elementsArray = objectArray.OfType<E>().ToArray();`

Comment: Excellent stuff, elementsArray = objectArray.OfType<E>().ToArray(); is what I am looking for.

Comment: s, Another related question, I want to set a particular element to null. The following code does not work.

elements[numElements - 1] = null: How do you do this? thanks

Comment: @Jeffrey From the example I gave you, if you do `OfType<string>` and then do `stringArray[0] = null` it works perfectly fine. You'd have to elaborate on the 'doesn't work' part. Maybe you're trying to set a value type to `null`...?

Comment: Hey Patryk yes I was trying to set a value to null, now I am using the following code  elements[i] = default(E); thanks

Answer (score 3):

You don't need cast here. Initializing array with capacity is enough:

```
elements = new E[INITIAL_CAPACITY];
```

Answer (score 0):

*elements[numElements - 1] = null:
What is the correct null value we should use in here then. thank*

The c# class has the 'default keyword' for your generics. Because some types might not be nullable.

```
var number = default(E);
```

For example an integer cannot be null.